# Can a moral code develop from one person's integrity?

Tags: metaethics, moral-agency

Just for a moment picture, not all the evil and bad in the world, but the good.

If you think about it and 'see' in your mind's eye all of the normal, everyday families in any given neighborhood who raise their children well and are pretty much model citizens, and, with a large dose of extrapolation, extend that image to include, first, the county in which you reside, then it is easy to see that the majority of citizens are law abiding, tax paying folks who respect the rule of law, serve the country if called upon and commit no crimes.

From there we move out; If you extend this to include the entire USA you can begin to see numbers veritably in the millions of quality people living their lives in peace.

Because I have traveled extensively in the world, I can assure that this pattern, of law abiding, societally conforming people is repeated nearly everywhere in equal numbers to that within the continental US.

By now, once we estimate the total number of these people by rough estimation, we can probably assume that there are literally billions of normal psychologically mature and responsible people living all across the globe.

Does this not indicate that there may be no need for a codified document to govern moral behavior? And further, even though the newscasts paint a negative picture of the world, does it not appear to be the case that human individuals are imbued with a very strong sense of what to do to secure a peaceful and productive life and need no help from ethical theories?

Comment: And how would the law abiding tax paying folk know how to law abide and pay taxes? How would they know how much taxes to pay and when? Or behave in tricky situations like abortion or euthanasia? Or when they do not have the expertise to decide? And even if their internal moral compass can tell them that in all cases how are they supposed to tune in to moral compasses of others to anticipate their actions so as to plan their own? Law and ethical theories are two very different things, codification is required for coherent coordination if nothing else, even if it were not informed by morality.

Comment: It's not. about a tax code or knowing how much to pay. It's about the cumulative organic effect of individuals acting on an innate grasp of working together without being told to do so. No one tells anyone that they must enlist and risk their lives in the Middle East. CMS

Comment: I do not see how "the cumulative organic effect of individuals acting on an innate grasp of working together" is supposed to answer the questions I asked.

Comment: "no need for a codified document" - are you talking about the Bible?

Comment: Presumably, before the advent of writing, people did just that. The fact that many off the oldest manuscripts are codifications of law, tells that societies _chose_ written law for a reason...

Comment: So does that mean that before you make any moral or ethical decisions that you personally refer to a written code. Can you share it with us or do you have it memorized? CMS

Comment: Why *any*? People do the most on intuition and/or habit. Written codes are consulted for fine tuning and close calls, but also increase confidence that others can be relied upon to do the same. The problem with the rosy sentiment of your proposal is that it falls apart even from small percentage of deviants, or just normal variations in behavior of the "law abiding folk". Not to mention that law abiding is a learned behavior that has to be reinforced. The "innate grasp" at levels required for social functioning is a fantasy, codes and enforcement are the crutches that prop it up in reality.

Comment: Your estimation of human integrity and reliability to know anything under their own innate intelligence marks a true believer in Skinner and the behaviorist legacy. That is only one measure of what comprises human nature. You speak as if that is the one and only measure. Added to that you apply the principle of the excluded middle to claim that 'integrity' falls apart. That is another highly dubious principle. No one in reality actually believes that statements concerning realtime situations are either true or false. Only artificial word games have rules like that. CMS